# How can I get all the file sizes of all the images/css/js on my website using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the file sizes of all my images/css/js from my website. How can you do this in nodejs?

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend is performing this operation after the page has loaded, and using a token-authorized client to determine the size of the page document, the resources it is using (both CSS and JavaScript) and the markup size.  On the server side, you'll receive an API request with all the files you need to [stat](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback).  Here's an example of what this could look like on the server side assuming the use of Express.js:

```
express.all('/api/pageSize',function(req,res,next){
    var fs = require("fs"); //Load the filesystem module
    var totalSize = 0;
    var pageURL = req.query.pageURL;
    var files = req.query.files;
    for ( var i in files ) {
        var stats = fs.statSync(files[i])
        total += stats["size"]
    }

    // do something with total size for this page
}
```